# Filtering using <a> tag

Tags: python, django

I have got some pictures with  tags on my page and I would like them to be used as filtering by the category. So after clicking on one of the pictures it would filter the results by the category.

So that would be the filter, that I would like to connect to one of the pictures:

```
item_list = item_list.filter(category__pk=1)
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-4 overlay zoom">
            <a href="/">
                <div style="position:relative;">
                    <img src="{% static '/img/category_choice/bike1.png' %}" class="img-fluid">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                        <h2 class="card-title"
                            style="text-align: center; color: aliceblue; position: absolute; bottom:5px;">
                            Gravel Bikes
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

plus list a the end of html file

```
<ul>
        {% for item in items %}
        <li>
            {{ item.title }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

views.py

```
def BikeView(request):
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
      item_list = Item.objects.all()
      item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
      context = {
          'items': item_list
      }
      return render(request, "bikes.html", context)
  return render(request, "bikes.html", {})
```

url

```
urlpatterns = [

path('checkout/', CheckoutView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
path('order-summary/', OrderSummaryView.as_view(), name='order-summary'),
path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
path('add-to-cart/<slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add-to-cart'),
path('add-coupon/', AddCouponView.as_view(), name='add-coupon'),
path('remove-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-from-cart'),
path('remove-item-from-cart/<slug>/', remove_single_item_from_cart,
     name='remove-single-item-from-cart'),
path('payment/<payment_option>/', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment'),
path('request-refund/', RequestRefundView.as_view(), name='request-refund'),
path('bikes/', BikeView, name='bikes'),
path('', HomeView, name='home'),
path('search/', SearchView, name='search'),
path('bike-category/<category_id>', category_view, name='category')
]
```

views

```
def category_view(request, category_id):
  item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__pk=category_id)
  return render(request, "bikes.html", {'item_list': item_list})
```

Comment: Ok, so you need the `<a>` tag to go to a view where you do the filtering, right? Where's your view?

Comment: @markwalker_ yes I want the <a> tag to go to the view and trigger ther filter. I have added the view to the post

Comment: And what's the problem with that? Besides it doing an unnecessary database call, it looks like it'd work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down. This is what we're going to do (trying not to modify that much what you currently have):

1.- Define a route to handle the requests when users click on the bike image. For this, we need to define a new path in the **urls.py** file of your app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ... ,
    path('bike-category/<category_id>', views.category_view, name='category'),
]
```

2.- Now, let's modify a little bit your **views.py** file and create a new view for showing the categories, since for what I see, you currently only have a view for filtering bikes according to a query parameter (that must be sent somewhere else in your code):

```
def category_view(request, category_id):  
    item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__pk=category_id)
    return render(request, "bikes.html", {'item_list': item_list})
```

3. Connect the href attribute of the `<a>` tag with the route we have just defined:

```
<a href="{% url 'category' category_id=1 %}">
```

Note that I have responded only based on your current code, therefore, I can't know if you have a static set of categories or if they are generated dynamically in the template, coming from the db, etc.

Comment: When I am trying to run the code I am getting an error `Reverse for 'category' not found. 'category' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` pointing to the BikeView, exactly to the last line `return render(request, "bikes.html", {})`

Comment: Double check that you have set `name='category'` in your path method, just as I've put it.

Comment: Oh, and please update the arguments that `category_view` takes. I've updated the answer, I forgot to set the argument `category_id`

Comment: I double checked everything, I have added everything to the post, can you take a look?

Comment: Okay, did you already updated this line -> `def category_view(request, category_id):  `?

Comment: Yes I did, and the error is still pointing to this line `return render(request, "bikes.html", {})` in BikeView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207626/discussion-between-revliscano-and-menor).